# What distribution fit test to use for binned data?

Tags: distributions, binning

I'm trying to compare two populations with 40 samples each. For each sample, I have two measurements of angle, measured in bins of 30 degrees (1-12), and I calculated the difference between the two (e.g. sample #1 has measurements of 1 and 6 which gives a difference of 6).

What test would I use to determine if the distributions of these differences are the same across both populations, two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test style? Some but not all data are normally distributed.

I know the two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test is what I want but that's for continuous data. There are various other distribution tests I've found (Anderson-Darling, Shapiro-Wilk, Lilliefors, etc) but I can't find anything that compares my two populations' non-normal distributions to each other.

Comment: None of your distributions will actually be normal. Your data are all paired values on a circle, where the angles have been binned? So... bin 12 is actually right next to bin 1?

Comment: I'm looking at the difference between the binned angles, so the distributions I want to compare are on a linear scale of 0=lowest and 6=highest. And yes I know they mostly are not normal distributions.

Answer (score 0):

The Mann-Whitney U test is a non-parametric test, which has as assumptions the independence between groups and that the data must be at least ordinal. From what you wrote, your data fulfills this.

The $H_0$ for this test is that both distributions are identical. Concretely: probability of an observation from population 1 being greater than an observation from population 2 = probability of an observation from population 2 being greater than an observation from population 1.

It would help if you provided more information about your data (e.g. editing the post, adding a sample with fake data), but from what you wrote, I would go with this test.

Comment: Mann-Whitney doesn't  detect general differences in distribution (e.g. change in spread with similar location)